# How to set an empty attribute using Jade?

Tags: html, pug

When using [jade](http://jade-lang.com/), [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) and [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) I prefer to use the translate directive as an empty attribute.

But for some reason, when using empty attributes in Jade, instead of getting something like `<tag translate` OR `<tag translate=''`, I'm getting `<tag translate='translate'`

How can I add an attribute without a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use the `{doctype: "html"}` when using the Pug (before was Jade) template engine.

This option [has been documented recently](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1313), but it does not states what is it for.

Bear in mind that since I'm just processing all the jade files using gulp, I don't care that much about partials and such things...

Caveats: as stated by [@lmacsen at github](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1180#issuecomment-30065840):

> This fail if you need to use that code into a partial html file.

I've come up with this answer after reading several other github issues in the project page.

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/201#issuecomment-1530205
https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1180

Comment: All links lead to 404 pages(

Comment: @DmitriMalyshev links fixed, please up vote if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Using `.foo(bar="")` and it produces `<div bar class="foo"></div>`.

Using `.foo(bar)` you will get `<div bar="bar" class="foo"></div>`.

I'm Using most recent versions of Pug (formerly known as Jade) and  I'm also using Partial jade files.